# Execution of Sleep () in Xlib programming

Tags: c, unix, graphics, x11, sleep

I have used a sleep() in the below section of code. However, to my surprise I found that sleep() is executed first and then the two lines used for printing pixels are executed. That means, I am getting both the pixels printed out at the same time after a 1 second wait in the beginning. However, I was supposed to get something like this, print a pixel, then wait for 1 second, and then print the next pixel. What could be the reason? Well, I am writing a X11 server display program.

```
  #include<xlib.h>
  #include<sys/time.h>
  ----------------  other header files
  ----------------
  int main ()
  ------------variables and few lines of code for X11 graphics

  XDrawPoint(.....);
  sleep(1);
  XDrawPoint(.....);

  ---------- Few other stuffs
  end
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in `XDrawPoint`. Maybe it only flushes the pixel (I'm just guessing now) when another pixel is being printed. (Just like printf flushes when a newline is detected).

Comment: An other guess: compiler optimization might change the order. It could be interesting to look at the assembly code

Answer (score 2):

XLib buffers some requests (like drawing operations), and flushes this buffer only if necessary. You can use the [`XFlush`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XFlush.html) after drawing the first pixel.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. It works. However, I was expecting by using Flush the earlier printed pixels will be vanished from the screen, but that didn't happen. Why so?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, by default X11 is a asynchronous protocol.

So use XFlush() or activate synchronous mode.

see http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XFlush.3.html for XSync command. Call Xsync with true.

Best regard

Comment: Thanks Emman. Yeah, XFlush() works, however I couldn't get rid of earlier pixels after using XFlush(). What I mean is if I want to print a new pixel after a certain time, I'm using XFlush() after the first print occurs. But, what should I do to erase the earlier pixels printed on window before calling XFlush()?